# Curious error in Beautiful Soup 4 for loop iteration

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site that loads its data in AJAX. I want to do this over a bunch of URLs that I've put in a list. I iterate using a for loop. Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import pdb

listUrls = ['https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-nxt-gold-32-gb/p/itmemzd4gepexjya','https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-on8-gold-16-gb/p/itmemvarkqg5dyay']
PHANTOMJS_PATH = './phantomjs'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)

for url in listUrls:
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    labels = soup.findAll('li', {'class':"_1KuY3T row"})
    print labels
```

When I run this code, I get the result for the first URL but the second one shows up with a blank list. I tried printing the soup for both the URLs and that worked. The error persists only when I'm printing labels. Labels for first URL gets printed but second list is empty.

```
[<truncated>...Formats</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">MP3</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Battery Capacity</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">3300 mAh</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Battery Type</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">Li-Ion</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Width</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">75 mm</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Height</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">151.7 mm</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Depth</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">8 mm</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Warranty Summary</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">1 Year Manufacturer Warranty</li></ul></li>]
[]
```

[Image:Result when I print labels in a loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sov1D.png)

I used interactive debugging module pdb to debug this further and a curious thing happened - when I add a stack trace before print labels and execute the loop step by step, it prints the labels list for the second URL as well.

```
for url in listUrls:
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser") 
    labels = soup.findAll('li', {'class':"_1KuY3T row"})
    pdb.set_trace()
    print labels
```

...

```
[<truncated>..."vmXPri col col-3-12">Depth</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">8 mm</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Warranty Summary</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">1 Year Manufacturer Warranty</li></ul></li>]
> /Users/aamnasimpl/Desktop/Scraper/web-scraper.py(12)<module>()
-> for url in listUrls:
(Pdb) n
> /Users/aamnasimpl/Desktop/Scraper/web-scraper.py(13)<module>()
-> browser.get(url)
(Pdb) n
> /Users/aamnasimpl/Desktop/Scraper/web-scraper.py(15)<module>()
-> soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser") #put all html in soup
(Pdb) n
> /Users/aamnasimpl/Desktop/Scraper/web-scraper.py(16)<module>()
-> labels = soup.findAll('li', {'class':"_1KuY3T row"})
(Pdb) n
> /Users/aamnasimpl/Desktop/Scraper/web-scraper.py(17)<module>()
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) 
> /Users/aamnasimpl/Desktop/Scraper/web-scraper.py(18)<module>()
-> print labels
(Pdb) n
[<li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Sales Package</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">Handset, Adapter, Earphone, User Manual</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Model Number</div><ul class="_3dG3ix col col-9-12"><li class="sNqDog">J710FZDGINS</li></ul></li>, <li class="_1KuY3T row"><div class="vmXPri col col-3-12">Model Name</...<truncated>]
```

[Image: Result when I run the code with stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q07di.png)

I've also checked each URL individually in the loop and it works fine. I'm new to programming and I'm at a loss now and would really appreciate any insight into why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could add the results / stack traces as text to the question instead of an image.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact it works while debugging simply suggests that this is a *timing problem*. When you debug it step by step, you basically give the page more time to load and hence the labels are printed correctly.

What you need to do is to make things more *reliable and predictive* by adding an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) - wait for at least a single label to be present on page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

for url in listUrls:
    browser.get(url)

    # wait for labels to be present/rendered
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li._1KuY3T.row")))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    labels = soup.select("li._1KuY3T.row")
    print(labels)
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe ! This worked. It isn't obvious to me though, if the loop works for the 1st URL, why do I need to add an explicit wait for it to work for the 2nd URL?

Comment: @dontpanic well, if you run the code, say, hundred times, I bet you would also see it failing on the first one too. The point, is the wait makes the code reliable, you don't make assumptions about the element being rendered at a certain point, you just explicitly wait for it. Consider accepting the answer to resolve the topic, thanks.